# displayNewMessageForm is not working when pop-ups are not allowed

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

I developed an add-in that uses displayNewMessageForm from API 1.6.
When submitting the add-in to office store, It got rejected because this function opens the new message form without any content despite the provided HTML content.
After testing I found out that when pop-ups are not allowed, the browser asks me if I need to always allow or block or allow once.
If I chosen allow once,  this function's behavior is opening empty new message form. and after choosing "always allow pop-ups", it's executed as expected. 
what is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you please specify the full API name and code sample? I don't recognize the API and version number you are talking about. Office-js does support displayDialog() API - but not sure if you are referring to the same one.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy I'm talking about outlook api 1.6

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(
  {
    toRecipients: Office.context.mailbox.item.to, // Copy the To line from current item
    ccRecipients: ['sam@contoso.com'],
    subject: 'Outlook add-ins are cool!',
    htmlBody: 'Hello <b>World</b>!<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></i>',
    attachments: [
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'image.png',
        url: 'http://contoso.com/image.png',
        isInline: true
      }
    ]
  });

Comment: this is a code sample from the documentation, this doesn't work for the first time also